# RAID 1 disk goes 100% activity all the time with 0 read/write with 0ms response

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, software-raid, raid-1, windows-10-v1709

I have setup software RAID 1 in windows 10 v1709. Main disk is SATA3 ssd but I have also two 3TB Seagate disks in software RAID 1 (mirrored). I have this setup for a few mounths and I had no problems with it until now.
One of the seagate disks goes 100% activity all the time even the read/write is 0 and the response time is also 0. After like 15 minutes of not using the disk it goes back to 0% but when I want to access that RAID disk only that one goes again to 100% and the response time is about 3000-12000 ms. Also I have to wait long time to acces foledr I just opened. I think the disk might be damaged or broken or it could be a software error.

Also sometimes the system freez out of nowhere, everything is fine and then I can not even press ctrl+alt+del .. I have to wait about minute to get back access.

hope you undesrtood my problem, my english isn't the greatest..

Comment: Did you check the event log?  You might see lots of port issued a reset warning.

Comment: I did not, but I physicaly disconnected one of drives (I had no clue which one, later I found out that it was the one with 100% activity) and as a miracle it works. I think it was some kind of error in widnows or in drivers or I don't know. But now I am copying all data to different drive and I am about to format both disks and pair them back in RAID 1 but this time using hardwere RAID card.. hope it will work .. anyway, thanks for response, hope I won't need any more help whith this..